# Cannot edit Software Sources after upgrading from 12.10 to 13.04

Tags: upgrade, software-sources

I go to System Settings -> Software sources. I see there many Software sources with the comment "disabled on upgrade to raring". When I click on the check-button or select ppa name to edit/delete that source nothing happens. This behaviour only occurs with sources inherited from 12.10. Sources added after upgrade can be removed correctly.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to click on check buttons just click on the ppa and the click on remove button below.

[image]

Comment: Even if I click in the name of the ppa, the remove button do nothing with sources inherited from 12.10. Selecting and removing sources added after upgrade works fine.

Comment: Try to upgrade to mainline kernel 3.9. [See here](http://www.liberiangeek.net/2013/04/ready-for-linux-kernel-3-9-install-upgrade-your-kernel-in-ubuntu-13-04/) for installation direction.

Comment: Nothing stated here works.